# XSLT - How to increase performance time

Tags: performance, optimization, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an XSLT code written to get the employee and manager hierarchy which is working as expected but its taking around 3 hours for 50,000 records.
I believe its due to loop while creating variables,

Trying to optimize but could not find a good solution yet, Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Current XSLT Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <!-- Identity template to copy the entire XML structure -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Template to generate the list of managers per employee -->
    <xsl:template match="employee">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <managers>
                <xsl:call-template name="findManagers">
                    <xsl:with-param name="employeeName" select="EmployeePositionID"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </managers>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Template to recursively find managers -->
    <xsl:template name="findManagers">
        <xsl:param name="employeeName"/>
        <xsl:param name="level" select="1"/>
        <xsl:if test="$employeeName != ''">
            <xsl:variable name="manager" select="//employee[EmployeePositionID = $employeeName]/Manager"/>
            <xsl:variable name="ManagerID_Var" select="//employee[EmployeePositionID = $employeeName]/Manager/@personid"/>
            <xsl:if test="$manager != ''">
                <hierarchy>
                    <xsl:attribute name="BottomToplevel">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$level"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="ManagerID">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$ManagerID_Var"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$manager"/>
                </hierarchy>
                <!-- Recursively call the template for the next manager -->
                <xsl:call-template name="findManagers">
                    <xsl:with-param name="employeeName" select="$manager"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
    <employee>
        <effectiveStartDate>2020-08-20T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
        <EmployeePositionID>1</EmployeePositionID>
        <PersonID>1111</PersonID>
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <ToBeHired>false</ToBeHired>
        <Manager personid="M1">2</Manager>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <effectiveStartDate>2020-08-20T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
        <EmployeePositionID>2</EmployeePositionID>
        <PersonID>2222</PersonID>
        <Name>Test2</Name>
        <ToBeHired>false</ToBeHired>
        <Manager personid="M2">3</Manager>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <effectiveStartDate>2020-08-20T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
        <EmployeePositionID>3</EmployeePositionID>
        <PersonID/>
        <Name/>
        <ToBeHired>false</ToBeHired>
        <Manager personid="">4</Manager>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <effectiveStartDate>2020-08-20T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
        <EmployeePositionID>4</EmployeePositionID>
        <PersonID>3333</PersonID>
        <Name>Test3</Name>
        <ToBeHired>false</ToBeHired>
        <Manager personid="M3">5</Manager>
    </employee>
        <employee>
        <effectiveStartDate>2020-08-20T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
        <EmployeePositionID>5</EmployeePositionID>
        <PersonID>4444</PersonID>
        <Name>Test4</Name>
        <ToBeHired>false</ToBeHired>
        <Manager/>
    </employee>
</company>
```

Output XML should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<company>
    <employee>
        <effectiveStartDate>2020-08-20T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
        <EmployeePositionID>1</EmployeePositionID>
        <PersonID>1111</PersonID>
        <Name>Test1</Name>
        <ToBeHired>false</ToBeHired>
        <Manager personid="M1">2</Manager>
        <managers>
            <hierarchy BottomToplevel="1" ManagerID="M1">2</hierarchy>
            <hierarchy BottomToplevel="2" ManagerID="M2">3</hierarchy>
            <hierarchy BottomToplevel="3" ManagerID="">4</hierarchy>
            <hierarchy BottomToplevel="4" ManagerID="M3">5</hierarchy>
        </managers>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <effectiveStartDate>2020-08-20T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
        <EmployeePositionID>2</EmployeePositionID>
        <PersonID>2222</PersonID>
        <Name>Test2</Name>
        <ToBeHired>false</ToBeHired>
        <Manager personid="M2">3</Manager>
        <managers>
            <hierarchy BottomToplevel="1" ManagerID="M2">3</hierarchy>
            <hierarchy BottomToplevel="2" ManagerID="">4</hierarchy>
            <hierarchy BottomToplevel="3" ManagerID="M3">5</hierarchy>
        </managers>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <effectiveStartDate>2020-08-20T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
        <EmployeePositionID>3</EmployeePositionID>
        <PersonID/>
        <Name/>
        <ToBeHired>false</ToBeHired>
        <Manager personid="">4</Manager>
        <managers>
            <hierarchy BottomToplevel="1" ManagerID="">4</hierarchy>
            <hierarchy BottomToplevel="2" ManagerID="M3">5</hierarchy>
        </managers>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <effectiveStartDate>2020-08-20T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
        <EmployeePositionID>4</EmployeePositionID>
        <PersonID>3333</PersonID>
        <Name>Test3</Name>
        <ToBeHired>false</ToBeHired>
        <Manager personid="M3">5</Manager>
        <managers>
            <hierarchy BottomToplevel="1" ManagerID="M3">5</hierarchy>
        </managers>
    </employee>
    <employee>
        <effectiveStartDate>2020-08-20T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate>
        <EmployeePositionID>5</EmployeePositionID>
        <PersonID>4444</PersonID>
        <Name>Test4</Name>
        <ToBeHired>false</ToBeHired>
        <Manager/>
        <managers/>
    </employee>
</company>
```

Comment: Please provide a small but representative example of the XML input and the expected output. Also why does your stylesheet say `version="1.0"` but the question is tagged `xslt-2.0`??

Comment: Performance issues can be specific to the processor being used, but very often using a **key** instead of a predicate like `employee[EmployeePositionID = $employeeName]` can be very beneficial. Using an explicit path instead of `//` can also help.

Comment: @michael.hor257k 
Thank you for responding, Have edited my post with Input xml and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The poor performance will be because of the instructions

```
<xsl:variable name="manager" 
  select="//employee[EmployeePositionID = $employeeName]/Manager"/>
<xsl:variable name="ManagerID_Var" 
  select="//employee[EmployeePositionID = $employeeName]/Manager/@personid"/>
```

which mean that for every employee, you are searching the whole file to find the manager of that employee, making the performance quadratic - O(n^2) - in the number of employees.

A few XSLT processors such as my company's Saxon-EE might optimize such expressions to use an index, but most are going to do a serial search through the document.

However, you can do the indexing "by hand" and this will greatly improve performance. Define an index like this:

```
<xsl:key name="empIndex" match="employee" use="EmployeePositionID"/>
```

and replace `//employee[EmployeePositionID = $employeeName]` with `key('empIndex', $employeeName)`.

You should also be able to achieve a saving by only doing the search once rather than twice: the second variable can be defined in terms of the first as

```
<xsl:variable name="ManagerID_Var" 
      select="$manager/@personid"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. 
Have replaced my code as you suggested by still not getting desired output. 


<xsl:variable name="manager">
   <xsl:value-of select="key('empIndex', $employeeName)"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="ManagerID_Var" select="$manager/@personid"/>

Comment: @vinaykumar, the suggestion is to use e.g. `<xsl:variable name="manager" select="key('empIndex', $employeeName)"/>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, Thanks . I tried as you suggested but i get a list of values of the node as shown below. Is it possible to just get a manager value. 

`<employee> <effectiveStartDate>2020-08-20T00:00:00.000</effectiveStartDate> <EmployeePositionID>1</EmployeePositionID> <PersonID>1111</PersonID> <Name>Test1</Name> <ToBeHired>false</ToBeHired> <Manager personid="M1">2</Manager><managers> <hierarchy BottomToplevel="1" ManagerID=""> 2020-08-20T00:00:00.000 1 1111 Test1 false 2 </hierarchy> </managers></employee>`

Comment: @vinaykumar There was no `xsl:value-of` instruction in my example, I don't know where you got that from. Generally, it looks as if you need to do some more background reading on XSLT because you are making some real beginner's mistakes: you give the impression you are trying to learn the language by trial and error.

Comment: @vinaykumar, your question is about a performance problem and the answer by Michael Kay is to use a key to fix that. He told you to replace the expression `//employee[EmployeePositionID = $employeeName]` by `key('empIndex', $employeeName)` but somehow you managed to mangle that to `<xsl:variable name="manager"><xsl:value-of select="key('empIndex', $employeeName)"/></xsl:variable>` which is completely wrong. My comment was to tell you were meant to use `<xsl:variable name="manager" select="key('empIndex', $employeeName)"/>`. That is all to fix your performance problem.

Comment: If you now have problems to apply that suggestion it will be hard for use to tell from some code sample in a comment what might be wrong, better ask a new question with specific details, where you put all details well-formatted in the question.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I appreciate your comments, i tried exactly the way you suggested.
You can try as well from your end with the input xml and XSLT i provided in my question.

Comment: @vinaykumar, my bad, for your original code and variable to use the key and fix the performance problem you want `<xsl:variable name="manager" select="key('empIndex', $employeeName)/Manager"/>`

Comment: And the other suggestion by Michael is to use `<xsl:variable name="ManagerID_Var" select="$manager/@personid"/>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, You are a rock star, Thank you so much. 
Appreciate your time in helping.
This is the part i was missing. It worked now.

Comment: @vinaykumar, don't forget to accept Michael's answer because he had it all right from the beginning on the XSLT level with the key declaration and on the XPath level with the use of `key('empIndex', $employeeName)`.

Comment: Sure will do, Thanks again @MartinHonnen and Michael